# Match only few words of a string and return boolean value

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the line which I have as a string : `"Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to ..."`

Now I want javascript to match the first few words or 2-3 words of this string and return boolean value true if it finds that 2-3 words in that string and false if it doesn't find it. Any idea how this can be achieved ? Thanks.

Comment: So you just want to return true if sentence has more than 3 words?

Comment: @anubhava Hmmm, I want it to return true if 3 words I am trying to find inside the string are found in it. For example, The string is : "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to ...". Now I want it to return true if I find "An active access" inside that string.

Comment: But that can be done with `if (str.indexOf('An active access')>=0)` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .indexOf function to find these few words in your string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

here is an example:

```
var string1 = "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to ...";
var string2 = "Warning: testfile, lorem ipsum";

alert( checkString(string1) );
alert( checkString(string2) );

function checkString(str) {
    if(str.indexOf("Fatal error") == -1)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

The function checkString will return true, if the string contains "Fatal error" (anywhere, not only at the beginning). You can change the function to match only the beginning of the string by changing it to this:

```
function checkString(str) {
    if(str.indexOf("Fatal error") == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do string matching of any type is with '[regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)'. This is a very common mini-language that has been implemented in many different programming languages, text editors and other places.

Here is where you lan learn the basics of regular expressions:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Here is where you can learn how to impliment it in javascript:

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Here is what javascript might look like doing a regular expression match:

```
var mystring = "Fatal Error: Uncaught Oauth..."
var pattern = /fatal.*error.*uncaught/i; // this is the regular expression
var result = pattern.test(mystring);
alert(result);
```

This will alert true.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to";
var res = str.split(" "); 
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) 
{
    //compare using res[i].equals(res[i+1]) method as many strings you need check
}
```